# Can I use OpenCV with a web app?

Tags: opencv, web-applications, web-deployment

I want to control my app using hand gestures. For various reasons I have chosen to make a web based app.

Is it possible to control/interact with a web app with OpenCV (or any other program)  running as an agent on the client, communicating directly with the page on the client rather than with the server?

The web app doesn't have to be in a common browser, it can be something like Qt WebKit. I am ok requiring the user to have an agent on their computer.

The server is not running locally!

Comment: https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv OpenCV bindings for node.js.

Comment: I am aware of this but I do not want to do for trips to the server. I want to run opencv on the client and talk to the JavaScript :)